# QtCreator Symbol is missing in Ubuntu 19.10 application

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

Using the recent Ubuntu distributions (up to 18.10.), after installation of Qt software, I could see and start the Qt-Creator in the application window. Now I have installed Ubuntu 19.10. and Qt 5.12.6 and there is no more Qt-Creator Button in the application window. Hence, I have  the problem, that I don't know, how to start Qt-Creator. I am asking for a solution. The button should apper within the buttos below.

[image]

Comment: Try to press `<Alt>+<F2>` and then type `qtcreator` and hit `<Enter>` to run the application.

Comment: Thanks, but that does'nt work.